# PHP / Zend Program architecture and Interfaces

Tags: php, zend-framework, interface, model

Hi guys i'm trying to wrap my head around where interfaces should be kept.

an example :

I have a zend mvc multi module application i have been working on and would like to clean it up ( its a real mess )

model objects include but not limited to:

```
Model_Order
Model_Order_Item
Model_Order_Item_Location
Model_Product
Model_Customer
Model_Warehouse
Model_Warehouse_Location
Model_Warehouse_Location_Position

dependencies include:

Model_Order : Model_Order_Item ( 1 order to many items ), Model_Customer ( many orders to one customer )

Model_Order_Item : Model_Product ( 1 item has 1 product )

Model_Product : Model_Warehouse_Location_Position ( a product could have many positions ), Model_Customer ( one to one relationship )

Model_Warehouse : Model_Warehouse_Location ( one warehouse could have many locations ( or bins ) and different types )

Model_Warehouse_Location : Model_Warehouse_Location_Position ( one location many product positions )

many of these are dependencies that traverse in both directions.
```

So my question is as follows.

When it comes to interfaces which of the following is appropriate ?

```
Model_Order_Item_Product_Interface
Model_warehouse_Location_Position_Product_Interface
```

inside Model_Order_Item may be a method setProduct(Model_Order_Item_Product_Interface $product)

inside Model_warehouse_Location_Position may be a method setProduct(Model_warehouse_Location_Position_Product_Interface $product)

then the model object would be

```
Model_Product implements Model_Order_Item_Product_Interface, Model_warehouse_Location_Position_Product_Interface
```

or

I have one interface outlining a product (Model_Product_Interface)

and inside Model_Order_Item may be the method setProduct(Model_Product_Interface $product)
But this means order needs a interface outside of its "namespace". ( BUT! instead now product is looking outside of its "namespace" to get all the interfaces it has to fit to)

I'm not 100% sure where to put these interface's

From a domain perspective looking at it as 4 separated groups orders, products, warehouse and customer. Having the interfaces designed within the "module"/group is better because its directly related to that.......

My mind can go in loops on this subject. I'm guessing its more of a personal preference ?

On a side note i also intend to use a singleton servicelocator to return services dedicated to each group and will hand back factories and data access objects ( along with other service related methods )

My idea being in the bootstrap of zend i would do all my dependency injection there so i have it in one place.

I appreciate any advice you can give me.

Comment: Your question seems to show that you do not fully understand the use of interfaces and classes. What does the `Model_Order_Item_Product_Interface` look like? Maybe showing one of those interfaces as an example will enable us to help you more.

Answer (score 0):

The first question you should ask is:

Who is the owner of this interface? Product?

Product_Model_Interface_Name

/modules/product/models/interface/Name.php

Why?

This way you will easily see who owns which model was used for its creation.

But if you're talking about a generic interface, then you must create a library

/library/MyApplication/Models/Interface/Name.php

***If you use Generic interface you will need to configuration autoload in your bootstrap***

Comment: All my models are in my library and i already auto load them thats not a problem.

I'm just trying to understand the process of grouping them better.

Answer (score 0):

I just put them in the library in an interfaces directory, so they don't clutter up my models directory. I use a structure in my library that mimics the ZF 1.x application structure:

```
/library
    /namespace
        /Application
            /Controller
                /Plugin
            /Interface
            /Model
                /Entity
                    /Abstract.php
                /Mapper
                    /Abstract.php
            /Resource
            /View
                /Helper
```

I know it's a little deep and busy, but it keeps me organized. When I change to ZF2 I'll have to reevaluate to implement namespaces.